# How can I remove a key value from foreach in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, phpmyadmin, conditional-statements

I have an array like this. Array name is *amount*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 207.2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 1458.8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 207.2
        )

)
```

Here I want to remove last key value from list when I display it into a table.

```
foreach(amount as key => values)
{
   print_r($values);
   echo"<br>";
}
```

When this print it should be show without last key element. like this

```
0
0
0
207.21
1458.8
```

I hope somebody will help me to solve this problem.

Hopefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the last value if the array, you can:

**First option**, you can use `array_pop` to remove the last value.

```
//Assign the values on a temp array
$tempAmount = $amount;

//Remove the last value of the temp array.
array_pop( $tempAmount );

//You can loop as usual the temp array
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

---

**Second option**: You can use a condition, like:

```
foreach($amount as $key => $values)
    {
        if ( $key < count( $amount ) - 1 ) {
            print_r($values);
            echo"<br>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to extract a sub-array from the index 0 and having size the size of old array - 1:

```
$newArray = array_slice($oldArray, 0, count($oldArray) -1);
```